# Tag name is not displaying in table column

Tags: rally

I am trying to get the tag name as a column using the following code:

Query Object:

```
var queryObject = {
                key: 'storiesBackLog',
                type: 'hierarchicalrequirement',
                fetch: 'FormattedID,Name,PlanEstimate,ScheduleState,Tags',
                query: '(ScheduleState = "Backlog")',
                order: 'FormattedID'
        };
```

Table Config:

```
var config = { columns: 
           [    
                {key:'FormattedID', header:'ID', width:60},
                {key:'PlanEstimate', header:'Points', width:60},
                {key:'Name', header:'Name', width:400},
                {key:'Tags.Name', header:'Department', width:400},
           ] 
        };
```

With Tags.Name the result is ... and with Tags the result is [object Object]. Does anyone know what the key needs to be?

FINAL SOLUTION:

```
rally.forEach(results.storiesBackLog, function(story) {
        var tags = [];
        rally.forEach(story.Tags, function(tag) {
            tags.push(tag.Name); 
        });
        story.TagNames = tags.join(';');
    });

    var tableBackLogConfig = { columns:
        [
            {key:'TagNames', header:'Department', width:400},
        ]
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the table component is smart enough to traverse down an object graph but I bet the fact that Tags is a collection is tripping it up.  You may need to process the data yourself first and add a column called TagNames to the table instead that you calculate yourself when the data is returned from RallyDataSource.

```
function onDataRetrieved(results) {
    rally.forEach(results.storiesBacklog, function(story) {
        story.TagNames = (story.Tags || []).join(', ');
    });

    var config = { columns:
        [ //...
            {key: 'TagNames', header 'Department', width: 400}
        ]
    };
    //create table 
}
```